# How to change SSRS Data Entry Field datatype to password?

Tags: xml, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that requires a secret key which is a parameter used in the SQL string. I would like the text in that field to be obscured while the report is sitting there open. If it were treated just like a password field in an html form, that would be perfect. Any way to get SSRS to do this?

I see in the RDL XML the field is defined like this:

```
<ReportParameter Name="secretkey">
  <DataType>String</DataType>
  <Prompt>Secret Key</Prompt>
</ReportParameter>
```

Is there a datatype like PASSWORD that would obscure the text string as in an html form?

Comment: Something to consider is that something like an HTML password form is not at all secure, just conveniently masked.  I don't believe that SSRS supports something like this but depending on how sensitive this string is, you may not even want a solution like this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is anything built into SSRS to support this, but what you could do is apply security permissions to the report so that only those who you would give this secret key to have access to the report.

Additionally, if you needed to limit or filter data in the report based on which user is running it - e.g. if there were different secret keys and they would tweak or modify the data displayed, the `UserID` built-in field may be useful for you.